# Cordova Network Plugin does not build on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

Having installed the `cordova-network-plugin` like so:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-network-plugin
```

to a working Cordova project (**build was successful on iOS previously**), the project inexplicably failed to build for iOS (`cordova build ios`).

It builds fine for Android, but produces the following error message for iOS:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress", referenced from:
  +[CDVReachability reachabilityWithAddress:] in CDVReachability.o
"_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName", referenced from:
  +[CDVReachability reachabilityWithHostName:] in CDVReachability.o
"_SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags", referenced from:
  -[CDVReachability connectionRequired] in CDVReachability.o
  -[CDVReachability currentReachabilityStatus] in CDVReachability.o
"_SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop", referenced from:
  -[CDVReachability startNotifier] in CDVReachability.o
"_SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback", referenced from:
  -[CDVReachability startNotifier] in CDVReachability.o
"_SCNetworkReachabilityUnscheduleFromRunLoop", referenced from:
  -[CDVReachability stopNotifier] in CDVReachability.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
Ld build/emulator/WowSuchApp.app/WowSuchApp normal i386
(1 failure)
Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/Doge/Desktop/WowSuchApp/cordova/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,WowSuchApp.xcodeproj,ARCHS=i386,-target,WowSuchApp,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,build,VALID_ARCHS=i386,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/Doge/Desktop/WowSuchApp/cordova/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/Doge/Desktop/WowSuchApp/cordova/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /Users/Doge/Desktop/WowSuchApp/cordova/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /Users/Doge/Desktop/WowSuchApp/cordova/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:134:23)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
```

To me, it seems the plugin is simply not compatible with `i386`, though I find this hard to believe. I therefore tried to compile it for `armv7`, using

```
cordova build ios --device
```

The error message is similar to that above, except alluding to `armv7` instead of `i386`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be that Cordova doesn't always add the required frameworks to your iOS project when you add a plugin.

Most projects will need the `AudioToolbox.framework` (debugging).

`cordova-plugin-network-information` will require the `SystemConfiguration.framework`.

`cordova-plugin-contacts` will require the `AddressBook.framework`, `AddressBookUI.framework`, and `CoreGraphics.framework`.

To add a framework:

1. Select your project in Xcode
2. Select your target
3. Select the **Build Phases** tab
4. Open the **Link Binaries With Libraries** expander
5. Click the **+**
6. Select your desired framework and add it to the project